# Trim mp4 videos in .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, video, mp4

I am developing an application where I deal with .mp4 videos. One of the features I would like to add to this app is the possiblity to trim/cut videos.

Therefore, I am looking for some SDK or other kind of solution that enables me to trim .mp4 videos.

I have tried cutting videos with Microsoft Encoder 4 Pro, but I cannot export them to .mp4, since the full version is needed. I wouldn't have trouble in paying for this full version, but then anyone who uses the application would have to afford it too.

Comment: I would probably just pass a call down to `ffmpeg`. Let it do the work for you.

Comment: Thanks for answeing Arran, do you know any example that shows how to do such thing? thanks